# What's the point of package modifiers?

Tags: java, modifier

I don't understand package modifiers (not annotations) like this:

```
public package foo;

public class Bar {
}
```

Do they have any meaning?

Comment: There is no such thing as a package modifier in Java.

Comment: but it is a valid java syntax

Comment: What do you mean by package modifier? "*but it is a valid java syntax*" no it is not, `public package foo;` is not valid in Java and will not compile.

Comment: Does this code compile with Oracle JDK?

Comment: No, it doesn't compile. I have never seen this ever being valid in any version of the java spec.

Comment: It does compile and it's perfectly valid code. It shouldn't but it does.

Comment: @biziclop : Do this compile with Oracle JDK?

Comment: @biziclop: If it shouldn't compile, then it's *not* perfectly valid code - and it definitely doesn't compile under all compilers. (It doesn't with Oralce's javac, for example.)

Comment: @JonSkeet I should've qualified it: it is recognised as valid code by Eclipse. It was just a reaction to the flurry of unwarranted downvotes. The question is perfectly reasonable, even though the answer to that may be "it's a bug in the Eclipse compiler".

Comment: @biziclop I believe that downvotes ware correct reaction on unclear question. Since OP didn't describe why (s)he thinks that this code is valid we can't do anything else than point to specification fragment which explains that it is not (+1 for Jon for finding such fragment). It most probably is a bug in OPs IDE but we can't be sure which IDE is it, so for now -1 from me until this question will be [edit]ed to include a way to reproduce this behaviour/problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The *only* type of package modifier in the JLS is an annotation. From [JLS 7.4.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.4.1):

> *PackageDeclaration:*
>   *{PackageModifier}* `package` *Identifier {. Identifier}* `;`
>
> *PackageModifier:*
>      *Annotation*

So `public package foo;` is invalid syntax.

This compiles under some versions of Eclipse, due to a [bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=384567) which has been fixed in some conditions, and will be fixed in all conditions from Eclipse 4.4 onwards.

Comment: In eclipse 4.3 it compiles (no error is shown, so I guess is a bug in that compiler

Comment: @Pablo : Does this compile with Oracle JDK?

Comment: @Pablo Ecplipse compiler and original Java compiler are not the same.

Comment: @Pablo: It doesn't compile for me under Kepler SR2.

Comment: @Pshemo I know, that's why I said eclipse compiler, I've found more than one piece of code that seems correct in eclipse but it does not compile using javac

Comment: @JonSkeet I'm using Kepler SR2 with JDK 1.6 (Java 6 compliance) and no error is shown :S

Comment: @biziclop: Thanks, will add it to the answer.