# Are there reserved package names in Java?

Tags: java

I have a package `com.test.mythingimport`. Ideally, I want this to be called `com.test.mything.import`. Are you able to name things with `import` or will it cause conflicts?

Comment: Why can't you try it out and find out?

Comment: You can't use keywords, it should be lower case, it must be an allowed directory, you can't have a file with the same name or any of its parents.

Answer (score 16):

From [JLS §7.4.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-7.html)

> A package declaration in a compilation unit specifies the name (§6.2) of the package to which the compilation unit belongs.
>
> ```
> PackageDeclaration:
>  {PackageModifier} package Identifier {. Identifier} ;
> ```

where `Identifier` is defined in [JLS §3.8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html) as

> ```
> Identifier:
>  IdentifierChars but not a Keyword or BooleanLiteral or NullLiteral
> ```

So a package name can specifically not be a keyword (such as `import`), a Boolean (`true` or `false`) or `null`.

Comment: "So a package name can specifically not be a keyword (such as import), a Boolean (true or false) or null.". It is not right.  `IdentifierChars` matter in the naming rules. And for example `foo-` is not valid as identifier.

Comment: Also that there is a `{ PackageModifier }` is quite interesting

Comment: @Lino Yeah. Turns out it can be only an annotation. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25644292/whats-the-point-of-package-modifiers#25644403).

Comment: how about 'native'? is it reserved by kotlin / android studio or java? didn't figure it out but it's also not allowed apparently
*edit: nvm it's under 3.9. Keywords thanks

Answer (score -1):

Package names are driven by the convention of file structure in Java. If you want your package to be named `com.test.mything.import`, your package needs to be in the `/com/test/mything/import` directory (where the root is the root of your source code for the project).

Comment: If you have the import keyword in the package name, you won't be able to import members of that package.